# Calculate average when checkbox are checked C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port, average

Good morning everyone!

So, I have 8 textboxes and under those are checkboxes. To those textboxes I'am always receiving data from a serialport and I need to do an average from those values. But I only want to do the average from the textboxes from which I checked the checkbox under them.

How can I add those values to the average formula when selected by checking the checkbox?

If anyone could help, I would really apreciate.

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write something like this :

```
       bool[] CheckBoxList { get; set; } = new bool[8];

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBoxList[0] = checkBox1.Checked;
            CalcAverage();
        }
        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBoxList[1] = checkBox2.Checked;
            CalcAverage();
        }
```

in CalcAverage method , Textboxes with a true value in the list are computed.